# How to convert escaped sequences to literal characters

Tags: python, rtf

I have to deal with rtf files where cyrillic characters are converted to escaped sequences:

```
{\rtf1\fbidis\ansicpg1251{\info{\title \'D1\'EF\'E8\'F1\'EE\'EA\'20\'E4\'EE\'EA\'F3\'EC\'E5\'ED\'F2\'EE\'E2}
```

I want to convert cyrillic symbols, but left rtf tags unchaged. Is there pythonic way to do it without third party apps (like OpenOffice)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can first make a list of the hex codes using a regex, then create a bytes object with these values, which we can decode. It appears that your data was encoded using "cp1251".

```
data = r"pg1251{\info{\title \'D1\'EF\'E8\'F1\'EE\'EA\'20\'E4\'EE\'EA\'F3\'EC\'E5\'ED\'F2\'EE\'E2}"

hex_codes = re.findall(r"(?<=')[0-9A-F]{2}", data)
encoded = bytes(int(hcode, 16) for hcode in hex_codes)
# or, as rightly suggested by @Henry Tjhia:
# encoded = bytes.fromhex(''.join(hex_codes))
text = encoded.decode('cp1251')
print(text)
# Список документов
```

Comment: Alternative: ```bytes.fromhex(''.join(hex_codes))```.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I had forgotten about this one!

Answer (score 1):

Despite @Thierry Lathuille's answer didn't solve the initial problem (I need rtf tags unchanged) it solved the most difficult part. So the solution to the initial problem:

```
string = "{\rtf1\fbidis\ansicpg1251{\info{\title \'D1\'EF\'E8\'F1\'EE\'EA\'20\'E4\'EE\'EA\'F3\'EC\'E5\'ED\'F2\'EE\'E2}"
hex_codes = re.findall("(?<=')[0-9A-F]{2}", string)
d = {"\\\'" + code: bytes.fromhex(code).decode("cp1251") for code in hex_codes}
for byte, char in d.items():
    string = string.replace(byte, char)
print(string)
# {\rtf1\fbidis\ansicpg1251{\info{\title Список документов}
```